# Want image to be shown on center for few seconds while going from (YDelta) to (toYDelta) in Translate Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation, translate-animation

I am creating Login page with animation like FB login . And i want my Logo image to be shown on center for few seconds while animated from Ydelta to Ydelta. 
Code :

```
 animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {


            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {



                        loginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Animation animFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                        loginBox.startAnimation(animFade);

            }
        });

        ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView );
        imgLogo.startAnimation(animation);

    }
```

**translate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="30%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Any type of Help , Appreciated !!
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what happens and what you expected? The code looks ok i guess. Translate in the imgLogo and after that fade in the loginBox.

Comment: @oberflansch yes it working fine but i want this image logo to visible on center of screen for few seconds and then move to YDelta position .

Comment: @oberflansch : i want either it stop at center for few seconds or start from center (wait few seconds ) and then move to (toYDelta) position .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two animations:

translate1.xml:

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
     />
```

translate2.xml:

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="50%"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="2000" />
```

With `android:startOffset` to delay the animation.

---

```
 moveToCenterAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate1);

 moveToCenter.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

            ...

            ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView );       
            Animation moveOnAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate2);
            imgLogo.startAnimation(moveOnAnim);

        }
    });

    ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView );
    imgLogo.startAnimation(moveToCenterAnim);

}
```

Comment: Hey , thanx . With this i understood and got the idea . Really Thank you.